# Cannot install gfortran after release upgrade

Tags: apt, package-management, 22.04, dependencies, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Ubuntu on WSL2 and recently upgraded from `18.04` to `20.04` and then to `22.04` by doing `do-release-upgrade` twice, which seemed to work fine. But now I cannot install `gfortran`:

```
>> sudo apt-get install gfortran

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cpp-11 : Depends: gcc-11-base (= 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) but 11.4.0-2ubuntu1~18.04 is to be installed
 gcc-11 : Depends: gcc-11-base (= 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) but 11.4.0-2ubuntu1~18.04 is to be installed
          Depends: libgcc-11-dev (= 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) but it is not going to be installed
 gfortran-11 : Depends: gcc-11-base (= 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) but 11.4.0-2ubuntu1~18.04 is to be installed
               Depends: libgfortran-11-dev (= 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

My `/ect/apt/source.list.d` contains

```
>> ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d
flexiondotorg-ubuntu-audio-bionic.list              flexiondotorg-ubuntu-nvtop-bionic.list              vscode.list
flexiondotorg-ubuntu-audio-bionic.list.distUpgrade  flexiondotorg-ubuntu-nvtop-bionic.list.distUpgrade  vscode.list.distUpgrade
flexiondotorg-ubuntu-audio-bionic.list.save         flexiondotorg-ubuntu-nvtop-bionic.list.save         vscode.list.save
```

but as far as I can tell everything was commented out after the upgrade to focal. Is there a way how I can solve this?